# Print module and missing breadcrumbs of Crumbs modules

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I use [crumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/crumbs) module to maintain custom breadcrumbs. Also, I use [print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module to maintain printer's friendly pages.

The breadcrumbs works perfectly in the ordinary pages. However, using print module leads to missing section in breadcrumbs.

For example:

mysite.com/sports/the-winner-cups
return breadcrumbs: Home -> sports -> the-winner-cups

but
mysite.com/print/sports/the-winner-cups

returns Home -> the-winner-cups

The following is a screen shot of active rules weigts of Crumbs module:
[image]

Comment: What is the router path for pages with mysite.com/print/... ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the router path for print/.. pages is always "print". See the print_menu() hook implementation in print.module.

You could write new Crumbs plugins for these paths (one for parent-finding, another for title-finding), with a logic somehow like this:

- The parent path for "print/a/b/c" is "print/" + the parent path of "a/b/c".
- The breadcrumb link title of "print/a/b/c" is the same as for "a/b/c".

The plugin could live in a custom module, or in the print module, or in the Crumbs module (patch welcome).

(This still needs some tinkering and experimentation. I'm afraid if I put it all into this answer, then I can as well just write the plugin myself and add it to the module - sorry..)